# NSLayoutConstraints in interface builder for 5 labels in a UIview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I think I have a fundamental issue with these new constraints.

Imagine you put 5 labels all going from top to bottom in a UIView.  The top label is equally spaced between the top of the view and the next label underneath it.  Then each label is also equally spaced.

What I would like to happen is that when the UIView height is made less or more the space between each label changes equally?

What should I be aiming for.  Should I make the 3rd label vertically centred in the view and then add constraints to the other labels from the centre or should 1 and 2 be constrained to the top of the view, 3 centre and 4 and 5 to the bottom?

Thanks in advance for all your suggestions.

**Edit:**
After the below answer was added I have played around with the constraints in interface builder and whilst I am not 100% sure I have answered it I think I have it working.

Between all labels I have a certain distance.  But I also have a certain minimum distance like following apples HIG I think it is 15 between labels.  So mine are at 30 and I set a constraint of greater than or equal to 15.  Now iOS does all the moving around from 30 to 15 for me when the superview changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally did this with buttons, and the only way I could make this work so that it would automatically adjust to the view frame size (on rotation) was to add labels (with no text, so they're invisible) between each button, and between the containing view and the first and last button. The buttons all had an intrinsic size and the labels did not, so they were free to change their heights to fill the space. I modified the code to use all labels, with the "b" labels being the ones with text.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableDictionary *viewsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
        UILabel *b = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44)];
         b.text = @"This is my label";
        [b setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [viewsDict setObject:b forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"b%d",i]];
    }

    for (int i=1; i<6; i++) { // these are the spacer labels
        UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc ]init];
        [l setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [viewsDict setObject:l forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"l%d",i]];
    }

    for (id obj in viewsDict.allKeys) 
        [self.view addSubview:viewsDict[obj]];

    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[l1][b1][l2(==l1)][b2][l3(==l1)][b3][l4(==l1)][b4][l5(==l1)]|"
                                                                   options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:viewsDict];

    NSArray *constraints2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[b1]"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:viewsDict];


    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints2];
}
```

This will produce evenly spaced labels with the standard space to the left edge of the view.

Comment: Thanks rdelmar, this looks good.  I think I have actually solved it with constraints.  At least so far it looks good.

Comment: @darbid, did you solve it in a different way, without using spacer labels? If so, you should post your answer.